# Ruby: Automatically set instance variable as method argument?

Tags: ruby, methods, instance-variables, argument-passing

Are there any plans to implement ruby behavior similar to the CoffeeScript feature of specifying an instance variable name in a method argument list?
Like

```
class User
  def initialize(@name, age)
    # @name is set implicitly, but @age isn't.
    # the local variable "age" will be set, just like it currently works.
  end
end
```

I'm aware of this question: [in Ruby can I automatically populate instance variables somehow in the initialize method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597249/in-ruby-can-i-automatically-populate-instance-variables-somehow-in-the-initializ/10855962) , but all the solutions (including my own) don't seem to fit the ruby simplicity philosophy.

And, would there be any downsides for having this behavior?

UPDATE

One of the reasons for this is the DRY (don't repeat yourself) philosophy of the ruby community. I often find myself needing to repeat the name of an argument variable because I want it to be assigned to the instance variable of the same name.

```
def initialize(name)
  # not DRY
  @name = name
end
```

One downside I can think of is that it may look as though a method is doing nothing if it has no body. If you're scanning quickly, this may look like a no-op. But I think given time, we can adapt.

Another downside: if you're setting other instance variables in the body, and you try to be readable by putting all the assignments at the beginning, it can take more cognitive "power" to see that there assignments also happening in the argument list. But I don't think this is any harder than, say, seeing a constant or method call and having to jump to its definition.

```
# notice: instance var assignments are happening in 2 places! 
def initialize(@name)
  @errors = []
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some pondering, I wondered if it's possible to actually get the argument names from a ruby method. If so, I could use a special argument prefix like "iv_" to indicate which args should be set as instance variables.

And it is possible: [How to get argument names using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622324/getting-argument-names-in-ruby-reflection).

Yes! So I can maybe write a module to handle this for me. Then I got stuck because if I call the module's helper method, it doesn't know the values of the arguments because they're local to the caller. Ah, but ruby has Binding objects.

Here's the module (ruby 1.9 only):

```
module InstanceVarsFromArgsSlurper
  # arg_prefix must be a valid local variable name, and I strongly suggest
  # ending it with an underscore for readability of the slurped args.
  def self.enable_for(mod, arg_prefix)
    raise ArgumentError, "invalid prefix name" if arg_prefix =~ /[^a-z0-9_]/i
    mod.send(:include, self)
    mod.instance_variable_set(:@instance_vars_from_args_slurper_prefix, arg_prefix.to_s)
  end

  def slurp_args(binding)
    defined_prefix = self.class.instance_variable_get(:@instance_vars_from_args_slurper_prefix)
    method_name = caller[0][/`.*?'/][1..-2]
    param_names = method(method_name).parameters.map{|p| p.last.to_s }
    param_names.each do |pname|
      # starts with and longer than prefix
      if pname.start_with?(defined_prefix) and (pname <=> defined_prefix) == 1
        ivar_name = pname[defined_prefix.size .. -1]
        eval "@#{ivar_name} = #{pname}", binding
      end
    end
    nil
  end
end
```

And here's the usage:

```
class User
  InstanceVarsFromArgsSlurper.enable_for(self, 'iv_')

  def initialize(iv_name, age)
    slurp_args(binding)  # this line does all the heavy lifting
    p [:iv_name, iv_name]
    p [:age, age]
    p [:@name, @name]
    p [:@age, @age]
  end
end

user = User.new("Methuselah", 969)
p user
```

Output:

```
[:iv_name, "Methuselah"]
[:age, 969]
[:@name, "Methuselah"]
[:@age, nil]
#<User:0x00000101089448 @name="Methuselah">
```

It doesn't let you have an empty method body, but it is DRY. I'm sure it can be enhanced further by merely specifying which methods should have this behavior (implemented via alias_method), rather than calling slurp_args in each method - the specification would have to be after all the methods are defined though.

Note that the module and helper method name could probably be improved. I just used the first thing that came to mind.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It definitely seems like more work that it's worth though. :)

Comment: @jackquack well, you really only have to do the setup once. Then in your classes, all you have to do is call `enable_for` and `slurp_args`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, actually...

```
class User
  define_method(:initialize) { |@name| }
end

User.new(:name).instance_variable_get :@name
# => :name
```

Works in 1.8.7, but not in 1.9.3. Now, just *where* did I learn about this...

Comment: +1 for a valiant attempt. Haven't tried it yet but it's more of a novelty if it doesn't work on 1.9.3.

Answer (score 0):

I think you answered your own question, it does not fit the ruby simplicity philosophy. It would add additional complexity for how parameters are handled in methods and moves the logic for managing variables up into the method parameters. I can see the argument that it makes the code less readable a toss up, but it does strike me as not very verbose.

Some scenarios the @ param would have to contend with:

```
def initialize( first, last, @scope, @opts = {} )

def search( @query, condition )

def ratchet( @*arg  )
```

Should all of these scenarios be valid? Just the `initialize`? The `@*arg` seems particularly dicey in my mind. All these rules and exclusions make the Ruby language more complicated. For the benefit of auto instance variables, I do not think it would be worth it.

Comment: I would envision a splatted instance arg to be `*@arg`. Other than that, none of the scenarios seem particularly ugly, complicated, or even hard to follow. In terms of instance var logic, you can already set them in the arg list, albeit in a contrived way: `def run(a = (@v=1)); end`. Yes, it's ugly contrived, and the var only gets set if no arg is passed. But it demonstrates that this kind of assignment is already allowed. I think it helps keep code DRYer. I'm going to add another example to my question.

Comment: Whoops, when I said it makes code DRYer, I meant the proposal in my question, not the contrived example in my comment.