# Quickly setting instance variables with options hash in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I want to use an options hash as input to a method in Ruby, but is there a way to quickly set all eponymous variables (i.e having the same name) instead of setting each individually?

So instead of doing the following:

```
class Connection
  def initialize(opts={})
    @host     = opts[:host]
    @user     = opts[:user]
    @password = opts[:password]
    @project  = opts[:project]
    # ad nauseum...
```

is there a one-liner that will assign each incoming option in the hash to the variable with the same name?

Comment: possible duplicate of [in Ruby can I automatically populate instance variables somehow in the initialize method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597249/in-ruby-can-i-automatically-populate-instance-variables-somehow-in-the-initializ)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
def initialize(opts={})
  opts.each { |k,v| instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v) }
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597249/in-ruby-can-i-automatically-populate-instance-variables-somehow-in-the-initializ/10855962 which is exactly what you are also saying. I will close my question as a duplicate, but upvote your answer.

Comment: Whitelisting the keys would be a good addition, a couple seconds to set up the whitelist now could save hours of debugging time later and help document the interface as a side effect.

Answer (score 4):

This should give you what you're looking for:

```
def initialize(opts={})
  opts.each_pair do |key, value|
    send("#{key}=",value)
  end
end
```

Comment: This only works if you have `setter` methods via `attr_accessor`, `attr_writer`, or manually created `setter` methods

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with,

```
 @host, @user, @password, @project  = opts[:host], opts[:user], opts[:password], opts[:project]
```

hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Besides Casper's solution, you could also use the [instance_variables_from](https://github.com/janlelis/instance_variables_from) gem:

```
instance_variables_from(opts)
```