# Shorthand way of assigning attrs in Ruby when using keyword args

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, this is a very common pattern:

```rb
class Token
  attr_reader :type, :lexeme, :literal, :location

  def initialize(type:, lexeme:, literal:, location:)
    @type = type
    @lexeme = lexeme
    @literal = literal
    @location = location
  end
end
```

In this code we are:

1. Passing a list of variables to an `initialize` method
2. Exposing that same list as `attr_readers`
3. Assigning the variables to ivars.

The purpose here is to make the passed variables available anywhere in the code, without having to reference with ivars.

There is a lot of of repetition here and I'm wondering if there is a shorthand way of doing this?

This example was taken from the [Building a Toy Lexer in Ruby](https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/building-lexer-ruby/) blogpost.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [in Ruby can I automatically populate instance variables somehow in the initialize method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597249/in-ruby-can-i-automatically-populate-instance-variables-somehow-in-the-initializ)

Comment: Thanks @JoelBlum but not really. That link is referring to a method without using keyword arguments.

The example code is also a bit hard to read.

Comment: The loop solution can still work for kwargs (by capturing them with **args), and possibly the Struct solutions can be modified. Ruby has no built in mechanism for this afaik.

Comment: Thank you @JoelBlum, it doesn't seem like there is a clean way of avoiding this duplication. I thought there might be some syntactic sugar I didn't know about.

At least I don't feel bad about using this pattern all over the place. :-)

Comment: Here's a related post from 10 years ago https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5825

Comment: Was proposed to add to Ruby this change but it has been rejected. :-( https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/17942

Answer (score 1):

You can just use Ruby's builtin `Struct` class:

```
MyClass = Struct.new(:type, :lexeme, :literal, :location) do
  def hello
    'world'
  end
end
obj1 = MyClass.new('a type', 'a lexeme', 'foo', 'bar')
```

Alternatively, you can also create a class which accepts keyword arguments in the initializer by passing `keyword_init: true` to the Stuct's initializer.

```
MyClass = Struct.new(:type, :lexeme, :literal, :location, keyword_init: true) do
  def hello
    'world'
  end
end

obj2 = MyClass.new(type: 'a type', lexeme: 'a lexeme', literal: 'foo', location: 'bar')
```

Please refer to [the documentation of the `Struct` class](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Struct.html) for details on how to use it.

With that being said, if you want to have full control over the class's layout, its exposed accessors and whether certain attributes are required or not, you may use your own custom class.

In the end, you will often have additional logic in the initializer to e.g. validate or convert given attributes to make sure they are expected values. With many reel-world classes, the conceived repetition is not actually an issue as the contained logic is often still specific enough to warrant this.

Comment: The latter requires the struct to be created with `keyword_init: true` to work properly

Comment: That's true, I fixed my answer.

Comment: (when given, it also prevents positional attributes)

Comment: Thank you @HolgerJust this solution might look a bit cryptic for people reading my code.